# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'grid'

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.title("GUI")

l1 = Label(window, text = "Hello!" ,font = ("Arial Bold",20)).pack()

bt = Button(window, text = "Enter").pack()

l1.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

window.geometry('350x200')

window.mainloop()
```

I got an error with:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'grid'
```

Comment: It is because `l1` is the result of `pack()` which is `None`.  Also you cannot use `pack()` and `grid()` together on widgets with same parent.

Answer (score 0):

It is because the variable `l1` is using `pack()` and you cannot use `pack()` and `grid()` on widgets that on the same parents/root (`Tk()` class)

To fix this you need to choose what layout system you want to use, if you want to use `pack()` layout system then remove the `l1.grid(row = 0, column = 0)`. If you want to use the `grid()` layout system remove the `.pack()` function on `l1`